# Program only runs from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, filenotfoundexception

I've written a basic program using Xamarin.Forms. I can run the UWP version of the program completely fine in both debug and release mode from Visual Studio 2017 with no crashes. However, if I try to run either the release or debug .exe directly from the file explorer, the program loads, but crashes almost immediately afterwards. There's no window that pops up for a split second; the program crashes without a trace. The same situation occurs on different computers. What's strange is that I could run either .exe directly about a week ago, and that everything stopped working only recently.

If I check the event viewer, I get a .NET Runtime error that states this:

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

I'm assuming this has to do with a blocked DLL or something auto injected by Visual Studio that isn't included in the build directories. However, I am unsure where I'm supposed to go from here and I've pretty much hit a brick wall in terms of research. How can I get the .EXE's running from the file explorer again?

Comment: The FileNotFoundException should list what file is missing. To simulate the error under debug, change the working directory in the projects debug settings, or from code, change the current directory like Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\temp".

Comment: @JoelLucsy After a day of running into a bunch of other problems, I was finally able to change the working directory and nothing changes. I still can't run the file directly and it only works in VS. Maybe I'm running the wrong file?